# JT400 Read File From IFS with user without password

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, jtopen

our problem is the following:

We have to connect to an ISeries with the JT400 and read a file in the IFS.
One requirement is the **job is running in the QBatch with a user without password.**
Our code is the following:

```
  //This wy we connect to the Iseries with the job credentials in this case 
   //user withou password
 AS400 as400 = new AS400(); 
 IFSFile file = new IFSFile(system, path);

  //This line throws the AS400SecurityException
 IFSFileInputStream fis = new IFSFileInputStream(file,IFSFileInputStream.SHARE_NONE);
```

**The last line throws this exception:
com.ibm.as400.access.AS400SecurityException: Password is not set**

We searched on internet but couldn´t find anyone with same problem

Thank you for reading our question

Comment: AFAIK, I don't see how that would be possible with jt400, without an user / password, you have no access to the iSeries server. Some reading: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-ifs/ One option could be to access it using an open network share, but that's unsafe and needs some setup on the iSeries

Comment: I'm confused...you say you need **to connect to an iSeries** and that **the job is running in QBATCH**  So is your java app running on one IBM i and connecting to another?

Comment: If you are accessing IFS on the same system, you can just use the standard Java IFSFileInputStream.

Comment: Thnk u ver much for all your comments, Charles, the java app is running on the Iseries, i get to connect using the job credentials but i get the exception when I use IFSFileInputStream fis = new IFSFileInputStream(file,IFSFileInputStream.SHARE_NONE); because job credentials have no password.

Comment: jweberhard I am already using IFSFileInputStream as whown in the question

Comment: What is `system` in your `IFSFile()` function? You create `as400`. Also, you don't supply a filename for IFSFile().

Answer (score -1):

Try connecting to the host using

```
AS400 as400 = new AS400("localhost","*CURRENT","*CURRENT");
```

See http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400.html#AS400(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: When coded as `AS400 as400 = new AS400();`, it should already default to *CURRENT/*CURRENT.